# Limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos( 4x)}{1-\cos (2x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos( 4x)}{1-\cos (2x)}$$

I don't understand how to answer it, please explain it I try to do double angle formula but it just made more confuse

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: A similar question: [Find $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\cos(2t)-1}{\cos(t)-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525373)

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{1-\cos(2x)}=\frac{1-(\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x))}{1-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}=\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{\sin^2x}=\frac{4\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}=4\cos^2x$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would assume so since you've done the problem for him.

Answer (score 1):

$$1-\cos(4x)=8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$
$$1-\cos(2x)=2\sin^2(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{1-\cos(2x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}{2\sin^2(x)}=4$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You also have $$1-\cos(4x)=1-\Big(2\cos^2(2x)-1\Big)=2\Big(1-\cos^2(2x)\Big)=2\Big(1-\cos(2x)\Big)\Big(1+\cos(2x)\Big)$$ Now, simplify.

Answer (score 0):

[L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule%20): differentiate both below and above:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4\sin(4x)}{2\sin(2x)}$$
That is also $\frac{0}{0}$, so again:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{16\cos(4x)}{4\cos(2x)}$$
Now just substitute $x=0$: and the limit is 4

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to remember that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{x^2}=
16\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{(4x)^2}=
16\cdot\frac{1}{2}=8.
$$
Moreover
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}=2.
$$

Can you go on from here?